# Adobe Acrobat DC uninstall fails with error "No valid sequence could be found for the set of patches"

Tags: adobe, sequence, patch, uninstallation, acrobat

Trying to remove Adobe Acrobat DC from Windows 10. The uninstall fails with error "No valid sequence could be found for the set of patches".
The corrresponding MS Error Code is 1648.

My version of Acrobat DC crashes (screen locks up) when I try to use certain features. I am only able to recover by using Task Manager to end the Acrobat DC process.

I found a similar issue on the [Adobe Support Community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/can-t-uninstall-adobe-acrobat-pro-quot-no-valid-sequence-could-be-found-for-the-set-of-patches-quot/td-p/13065541) that suggests running Adobe's "Creative Cloud Cleaner" which generates the same error.

Microsoft has a [utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d) for uninstalling programs. This also failed.

I was unsuccessful finding any other clues on Google, Acrobat Community, or on StackOverflow

I am running Windows 10 x64, Version 22H2,